# Passing an object around increases retain count

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

iOS, transitioning to ARC. I've observed a curious behavior regarding CF/NS bridging. In the following scenario:

```
CFStringRef cfs = ComesFromSomewhere();
NSString *ns = (__bridge NSString*)cfs;
```

the retain count of the string object is 2 at the end. However, in the following:

```
NSString *ToNS(CFStringRef cfs)
{
    return (__bridge NSString*)cfs;
}

CFStringRef cfs = ComesFromSomewhere();
NSString *ns = ToNS(cfs);
```

the retain count is 3 at the end. What's going on, please? Who holds the extra reference? Is the object being added to the autorelease pool by the mere act of passing it around?

Preemptive response to "don't worry, ARC *just works*": I'm mixing Core Foundation with Cocoa here, no way around it. This is leak prone. Without the ability to account for the retain counts explicitly, I'm flying blind.

EDIT: it's an artifact of the debug build. In the release build, the retain count under the latter scenario is still 2.

There's a tangible difference between a fragment that leaves large autoreleased objects around and one that doesn't; you don't want the former in a big loop without a pool in the loop body. Helps to know it's an artifact of zero optimization, but still, not cool.

Comment: Do you have a debug watch or something else on the variable? That might be keeping the variable alive you you can inspect it.

Comment: Doesn't account for the discrepancy. The function introduces no extra variables, nothing to watch.

Comment: The instruments tool `leaks` might be helpful in this situation, although sometimes regardless it's like trying to a needle in a haystack.

Comment: There's no leak, I've checked. It really looks like a hidden retain/autorelease. But I'd prefer a confirmation.

Comment: "Without the ability to account for the retain counts explicitly, I'm flying blind." Not if you use the static Analyzer. It would tell you if you were mismanaging memory.

Comment: Even the NS/CF boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CFStringRef cfs = ComesFromSomewhere();

// retainCount -> 1

NSString *ns = ToNS(cfs);

// ToNS(cfs)
//
// ToNS is not object creating method,
// thus the returned object was automatically autoreleased
// retainCount += 1

// NSString *ns
// 
// It's __strong variable, ns variable has an ownership of the object
// retainCount += 1

// retainCount -> 3
```

The definition of `object creating method` is a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, of a Objective-C class. See [Basic Memory Management Rules - You own any object you create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

> In the release build, the retain count under the latter scenario is still 2.

Also compiler can omit to send autorelease message to object if it's eligible.

**EDITED**

You can use C++ reference to avoid autorelease.

```
void ToNS(CFStringRef cfs, NSString __strong *& ns)
{
    ns = (__bridge NSString*)cfs;
}

NSString *nsstr;
ToNS(cfstr, nsstr);

// retainCount -> 2
```

**EDITTED**

```
NS_RETURNS_RETAINED NSString *ToNS(CFStringRef cfs)
{
    return (__bridge NSString*)cfs;
}
```

NS_RETURNS_RETAINED makes the framework treat the function as an object creating one (which it really is). Cocoa has a name convention that lets you designate a method as an object creator, but the convention only applies to Objective C class methods, not to C style functions and not to C++ class member functions.

Comment: So no way to designate a C/C++ function as an object creating one, short of wrapping in a static class method?

Comment: Updated my answer for avoiding autorelease.

Comment: Looks like the ns_returns_retained attribute will also do the trick... Let me test.

Comment: Tested, annotating with NS_RETURNS_RETAINED reduces the count to 2. Only you have to place the attribute in the leading position, before the return type. Edited.